# Rules for combining pipe and parentheses in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pipe, parentheses

In ruby you can do things like:

```
[[:a, [:z, 1]]].map{|one, (two, three)| three}
=> 1
```

What are limits and general rules in combining pipe sections with parentheses?

Comment: No limits. This is a regular array destructuring, so the same rules apply.

Comment: As @Sergio says, this is called "array destructuring" or [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). It is a powerful and useful technique. See, for example, [this article](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/) and [this article](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/), the later focusing on a central construct in array decomposition, the "splat".

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure how this language feature was called. Now i can do further research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, this is called "array destructuring" or array decomposition. See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition .